# How to upload a .rdl report to CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, crm, rdl

I have downloaded one of the system generated reports from CRM 2011, it saved as a .RDL file which I then opened and modified.

My question is, how do I then upload the modified report back to CRM. I have tried using the report wizard and searching for the existing file however it just kicks back an error message:

```
Query Build Error:
The specified record type does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
```

It has not been developed on the SSRS or using BIDS, and I haven't created it using FETCH, all I have done is save the report to my desktop, modify some of the record names and then try to upload it again.

It is starting to annoy me now because having searched through the length of google and nearly every post I have seen has stated this is the exact way to upload custom reports.

Is there any reason why it is not working for me?

Comment: it is CRM Online? did you modify a built-in report, correct?

Comment: Its not online no and yea I did.
I exported one report from CRM, changed some of the field/table names and then tried to import it again.
I just cannot fathom why I'm getting this error message :S

Comment: did you select the report, clicked the `edit` button and after `browse` under `File Location` to upload the rdl file?

Comment: I'm uploading it as a new report but in essence yea thats exactly what I did

Comment: can you specify this part: "modify some of the record names"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Workplace.
2. Click on Reports Entity.
3. Click on New Report.
4. Select Report Type as Existing File.
5. Click on Browse and select the .rdl Report file.

Comment: However, if you update the existing report, you have to use different rdl file name otherwise CRM does not recognize that you are uploading new version of RDL file.

Answer (score 1):

It won't let you upload the file that way.  You need to either edit an existing report or create a new report.

**NEW**

1. Reports
2. Click New
3. Report Type:Existing File
4. Choose File
5. Finish filling out required fields

**EXISTING**

1. Reports
2. Select a report & Click the Edit button
3. Report Type:Existing File
4. Choose File
5. Save